# Not able to access a element using LINQ and XDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a piece of xml that I am getting as a response from a web service.

```
 <Production>
    <creator>...</creator>
    <creator.date_of_birth/>
    <creator.date_of_death/>
    <creator.history/>
    <creator.lref>426</creator.lref>
    <creator.qualifier/>
    <creator.role/>
    <creator.role.lref/>
    <production.notes/>
    <production.place>France</production.place>
    <production.place.lref>30</production.place.lref>
  </Production>
  <production.period>19th century</production.period>
  <production.period.lref>13</production.period.lref>
  <Production_date>
    <production.date.end>1863</production.date.end>
    <production.date.end.prec>circa.</production.date.end.prec>
    <production.date.start>1863</production.date.start>
    <production.date.start.prec>dated</production.date.start.prec>
  </Production_date>
```

Below is my LINQ code to get the values:

```
allrecs = (from XElement c in recordSet.Descendants("recordList")
                where c.HasElements
                from x in c.Elements("record")
                select new CollectionRecord()
                {
                  production_place =  x.Element("Production").Element("production.place").Value,
                  production_period =  x.Element("production.period").Value,
                  production_start_date = x.Element("Production_date").Element("production.date.start").Value,
                  production_end_date = x.Element("Production_date").Element("production.date.end").Value,
                }).ToList <CollectionRecord>();
```

The problem I have found is - I am not able to get the value for "production.date.start" and "production.date.end" but the above code works for "production.period". There is nothing wrong with the xml structure and the data in those elements. According to my understanding, it is not working with any element that is like - "a.b.c" but it works well with - "a.b" as I have checked with other similar elements and it doesn't work!

Comment: could pls check ur XML once again. b'cas i got an error when i pasted on XMLFile it shows a error "XML Document cannot have multiple root level element" also validate your XML here http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/

Comment: @Shankar - it's only a fragment of the document that's been pasted here - just wrap it in a single node and it'll work

Comment: @SidP okay...below posted ans has soln to ur query... or still searching?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me (I've kept your XLinq code identical - just swapped over to anon type for the `new`):

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
  XElement x = XElement.Parse(@"<record><Production> 
<creator>...</creator> 
<creator.date_of_birth/> 
<creator.date_of_death/> 
<creator.history/> 
<creator.lref>426</creator.lref> 
<creator.qualifier/> 
<creator.role/> 
<creator.role.lref/> 
<production.notes/> 
<production.place>France</production.place> 
<production.place.lref>30</production.place.lref> 
</Production> 
<production.period>19th century</production.period> 
<production.period.lref>13</production.period.lref> 
<Production_date> 
<production.date.end>1863</production.date.end> 
<production.date.end.prec>circa.</production.date.end.prec> 
<production.date.start>1863</production.date.start> 
<production.date.start.prec>dated</production.date.start.prec> 
</Production_date></record>");
  var rec = new 
              {
                production_place = x.Element("Production").Element("production.place").Value,
                production_period = x.Element("production.period").Value,
                production_start_date = x.Element("Production_date").Element("production.date.start").Value,
                production_end_date = x.Element("Production_date").Element("production.date.end").Value,
              };
  Assert.AreEqual("France", rec.production_place);
  Assert.AreEqual("19th century", rec.production_period);
  Assert.AreEqual("1863", rec.production_start_date);
  Assert.AreEqual("1863", rec.production_end_date);
}
```

I'm wondering if your `CollectionRecord` class is using properties and whether you've written the `set` methods correctly for the two offending values?

(Update) Since your get/sets are 'standard' it could be something as simple as a piece of code somewhere physically setting those properties to null somewhere.

Comment: Below is my get/set methods for those two values.

'public string Production_start_date
        {
            get
            {
                return production_start_date;
            }
            set
            {

                production_start_date = value;
            }
        }

        public string Production_end_date
        {
            get
            {
                return production_end_date;
            }
            set
            {

                production_end_date = value;
            }
        }'

Comment: Well there must be something else outside of the code you've posted then.  My code here uses identical XML to yours and identical XLinq operations; all I've changed is the use of the `CollectionRecord`, since I don't have that class; oh and it's not a collection.

I suggest you copy and paste my code into a test, and then change that anonymous type to a `CollectionRecord` instance.  If the test passes, then I'll wager something is nulling those properties after you set them.

Comment: I have again tried your above code without using my CollectionRecord 
` var query = (from XElement c in recordSet.Descendants("recordList")
                    where c.HasElements
                    from x in c.Elements("record")
                    select new{
                
                production_start_date = x.Element("Production_date").Element("production.date.start").Value,
                production_end_date = x.Element("Production_date").Element("production.date.end").Value,
              });`

It doesn't work and says that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: That's a problem outside what we're talking about - this `NullReferenceException` must be something to do with your XML - **please paste my code exactly into a unit test class and replace the anonymous new with your CollectionRecord and verify that it works.** When that passes (which it will) you will see that it's not your Linq to XML code (which I've copied *exactly*) that's the issue but something else outside of what you've posted here.